# Position top/left при drag'n'drop

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-n-drop, атрибуты

Есть проблема с присвоением значений аргументам.
Есть следующий код- [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udyczgej/)

К сожалению там не реализован `dragdrop`, но в проекте по факту он есть.

При перетаскивании зеленого квадрата (`draggable`) на зону жёлтого квадрата (`droppable`),
у него сохраняются позиции "top" и "left", хотя я принудительно их изменил.

Инспектор кода браузера показывает следующее:

```
element.style {
position: relative;
left: 2px;
top: 5px;}

testsyle.css:18
div.droppable .draggable {
margin: auto;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос 1 - как присвоить им значение`0` top и left.
вопрос 2 - как по другому их переместить в желтые квадраты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He

```
   $(el).attr("left", "0px")
       .attr("top", "0px");
```

a

```
a.css("left", "0px").css("top", "10px");
```