# Объявить, но не вызвать jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

Может глупый вопрос, заранее извиняюсь.
Столкнулся с тем, что при создании функции сразу же ее инициализирую.

```
 function firstType() {
    setInterval(function () {
        xMass.forEach(function (element) {
            element.removeClass('active');
            console.log('1')
        });
    }, 500);

    setInterval(function () {
        xMass.forEach(function (element) {
            element.addClass('active');
        })
    });
}
```

А мне надо, чтобы она вызывалась по нажатию:

```
  $('button.start-first').on('click', firstType());
```

И тут я понял, что ничего не понял, я объявляю функцию, но не вызываю ее. Почему при перезагрузке страницы, у меня сразу же включатся эта функция автоматом.
Более того.
Я не могу остановить ее

```
function stopLight () {

    window.clearTimeout(secondType);}
 $('button.stop').on('click', stopLight);
```

Подскажите, где  я туплю. Заранее спасибо.

Полный *.js =

```
let one = $('div.one'),
    two = $('div.two'),
    three = $('div.three'),
    four = $('div.four'),
    five = $('div.five'),
    six = $('div.six'),
    seven = $('div.seven');

let xMass = [
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four,
    five,
    six,
    seven
];


function firstType() {
    setInterval(function () {
        xMass.forEach(function (element) {
            element.removeClass('active');
            console.log('1')
        });
    }, 500);

    setInterval(function () {
        xMass.forEach(function (element) {
            element.addClass('active');
        })
    });
}

function secondType () {
    setInterval(function () {
        massiveNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        xMass[massiveNumber].addClass('active');
        console.log('2')
    }, 100);

    setInterval(function () {
        massiveNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        xMass[massiveNumber].removeClass('active')
    }, 100);
}



    $('button.start-first').on('click', firstType());

    $('button.start-second').on('click', secondType());



function stopLight () {

    window.clearTimeout(secondType);
    window.clearTimeout(firstType);
}

    $('button.stop').on('click', stopLight);
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778920/position-top-left-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-dragndrop

Comment: @Igor, спасибо) лучше поздно чем никогда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('button.start-first').on('click', firstType);
```

Посмотрите, что подается в `clearInterval` в качестве параметра:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Заодно посмотрите, какие параметры обязательны в вызове `setInterval`:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp